# Set width of GridView DateItem based on content

Tags: asp.net

I am binding all the columns of the dataSource using `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` property. Width of the `header cell` is default width of GridView column.

The purpose is to create a decent table layout, with minimal work on markup. Thus trying to skip binding each column explicitly.

Is there a way to achieve this in `GridView` i.e. to set width of column based on content of the cell. i.e.

```
<tr><th>DummyHeaderContainingMoreLength</tr></th>
<tr><td>cellContent</tr></td>
```

Can I obtain width of the cell as `lengthof(cellContent)`, let the header float or truncate.

Comment: what do mean by based on cell content?

Comment: @EmmanuelN, Have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: you want to do it on server side or client side?

Comment: @EmmanuelN It would be good if I could do this by setting property of GridView on server side.

Answer (score 1):

Set width="100%". This will do.

Comment: Where should I set this value.

Comment: I am binding columns with `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`. So, I do not have access to td element.

Comment: <asp:GridView Width="100%" runat="server" ID="gridview1"  AllowSorting="true" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true">